# Difference in rose seedlings with red or green seed leaves

Tags: botany

I tried to sowing roses from rose hips the first time. (In autumn I collected some rose hips random from different bushes in the neighborhood. I mixed the seeds while sowing.) Now the seedlings grow one after another. Thereby I noticed, that some have their first leaves in a more red color, and others in a clear green.

Could I conclude some characteristics of the grown up plant out of this?

(I tried to search for "roses red or green leaves" but only get an amount of results with red petals...)

[image: two rose seedlings, one with red and one with green seed leaves]

Comment: The first leaves of dicotyledon plants are called the cotyledons. Similarly, the scientific word for colour is pigmentation. Even searching with those terms though, I haven't been able to find an answer - I guess you'll have to find out for yourself!

Comment: @smartse If there is no answer here in around 6 month - AND I am remembering my question - I will write an answer myself ;)